# Scala collect function

Tags: scala

Let's say I want to print `duplicates` in a **list** with their `count`. So I have `3 options` as shown below:

```
  def dups(dup:List[Int]) = {
     //1)
     println(dup.groupBy(identity).collect { case (x,ys) if ys.lengthCompare(1) > 0 => (x,ys.size) }.toSeq)
     //2)
     println(dup.groupBy(identity).collect { case (x, List(_, _, _*)) => x }.map(x => (x, dup.count(y => x == y))))
    //3)
     println(dup.distinct.map((a:Int) => (a, dup.count((b:Int) => a == b )) ).filter( (pair: (Int,Int) ) => { pair._2 > 1 } ))

  }
```

**Questions:**

-> For `option 2`, is there any way to name the list parameter so that it can be used to append the size of the list just like I did in `option 1` using ys.size?

-> For `option 1`, is there any way to avoid the last call to toSeq to return a List?

-> which one of the 3 choices is `more efficient by using the least amount of loops`?

As an example input: List(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,100,101,101,102)
Should print: List((1,3), (5,2), (101,2))

Based on @lutzh answer below the best way would be to do the following:

```
val list: List[(Int, Int)] = dup.groupBy(identity).collect({ case (x, ys @ List(_, _, _*)) => (x, ys.size) })(breakOut)
 val list2: List[(Int, Int)] = dup.groupBy(identity).collect { case (x, ys) if ys.lengthCompare(1) > 0 => (x, ys.size) }(breakOut)
```

Comment: What do you mean with avoid the last call to `toSeq` to return a `List`? What else should it return?

Comment: The collect call at 1) produces a Map you can see if you print the call a list of (1 -> 3) , (4 -> 4) etc. So you need the toSeq if you want to print an actual list of pairs which is creating a collection by looping again thru the elements. So I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this since in the call I am actually producing a pair (x,ys.size) I would think it would converted automatically to a sequence but instead it keeps the Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For option 1 is there any way to avoid the last call to toSeq to
>   return a List?

`collect` takes a `CanBuildFrom`, so if you assign it to something of the desired type you can use [breakOut](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html):

```
import collection.breakOut
val dups: List[(Int,Int)] = 
    dup
    .groupBy(identity)
    .collect({ case (x,ys) if ys.size > 1 => (x,ys.size)} )(breakOut)
```

`collect` will create a new collection (just like `map`), using a `Builder`. Usually the return type is determined by the origin type. With [breakOut](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html) you basically ignore the origin type and look for a builder for the result type. So when `collect` creates the resulting collection, it will already create the "right" type, and you don't have to traverse the result again to convert it.

> For option 2, is there any way to name the list parameter so that it
>   can be used to append the size of the list just like I did in option 1
>   using ys.size?

Yes, you can bind it to a variable with @

```
val dups: List[(Int,Int)] = 
    dup
    .groupBy(identity)
    .collect({ case (x, ys @ List(_, _, _*)) => (x, ys.size) } )(breakOut)
```

> which one of the 3 choices is more efficient?

Calling dup.count on a match seems inefficient, as dup needs to be traversed again then, I'd avoid that.

My guess would be that the guard (if lengthCompare(1) > 0) takes a few cycles less than the List(*,*,_*) pattern, but I haven't measured. And am not planning to.

Disclaimer: There may be a completely different (and more efficient) way of doing it that I can't think of right now. I'm only answering your specific questions.

Comment: So I have accepted your answer and edit my question to reflect what the best option would be. Would you care to add a comment about the breakOut option at the end. I believe this works inside the collect to force it to produce the desired collection in my case a List[(Int,Int)] without any extra work. I still not sure if there is any performance difference between using lengthCompare (which is very efficient since it only checks that the list has at least one in this case) and the unapply on the list that checks that it has at least 2 elements.

Comment: Edited a bit to add information on breakOut. Good point on lengthCompare, I used size out of laziness/habit. Especially in a general case, if you want it to work on any kind of collection, lengthCompare is probably better.